# Multiple lines in UITabBarItem Label

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem

I've tried many things but impossible to find a way to put the label of a UITabBarItem with a lineNumber customised.0 (i would like to get the title on 2 lines).

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: you want label in UITabBarItem its mean you also want its touch event (i guess) ? then you can directlly use UIButton with multiple lines.

Comment: The "title label" is not exposed... You will almost certainly need to use a custom tab bar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now it contains two subviews. At 0 it is imageView and at 1 it is label.
Now make the height of `imageview` a bit smaller so that you can give the height of label a bit larger to have multiple lines. Set the property `ofnumberoflines` of the label to 0 via code.

```
let viewTabBar = tabBarItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
let imageView = viewTabBar?.subviews[0] as? UIImageView
let label = viewTabBar?.subviews[1] as? UILabel
```

and now play with this label.

Comment: You should get a medal for that ;) I'm pretty sure your answer will help tons of people !

Comment: note that if you dont have image, the index of UILabel will be 0, I've posted more generic solution below

Comment: Can you please explain it, what is the value for key 'view'? When I run this code, I'm getting viewTabBar as nil.

Comment: This is an incomplete answer, with no proof it works.  How do you move the image and label upwards, make the tabbar higher, and then account for the two lines?  All this does is show how TabBarItems has subviews.  It's not an answer.

Comment: @Arnav reference to your answer, possible can I ask question `tabbar item title` related?

Comment: yups...How can I help you @Tekhe

Comment: @Arnav Is Multiline tabbar title works on iPhone 8 ? Its working on İPhone X, 11 or pro max series but not on iPhone 8. I have tried your solution as well but no.

Comment: As per John Pitts comment, this doesn't show the details of what needs to be done. See [Was'Siim's more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60320339/199364) for a complete solution.

Answer (score 5):

More stable solution:

```
guard let view = tabBarItem?.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView,
        let label = (view.subviews.compactMap{ $0 as? UILabel }).first,
        let imageView = (view.subviews.compactMap{ $0 as? UIImageView }).first else { return }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution for that

We need to implement this inside `viewwillLayoutSubviews`, to update the UI and make it works.

In this example in going to customize my 3rd tab bar item only

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    // acess to list of tab bar items
    if let items = self.tabBar.items {
        // in each item we have a view where we find 2 subviews imageview and label
        // in this example i would like to change
        // access to item view
        let viewTabBar = items[2].value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
        // access to item subviews : imageview and label
        if viewTabBar.subviews.count == 2 {
            let label = viewTabBar?.subviews[1]as? UILabel
            // here is the customization for my label 2 lines
            label?.numberOfLines = 2
            label?.textAlignment = .center
            label!.text = "tab_point".localized
            // here customisation for image insets top and bottom
            items[2].imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the result
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    tabBar.items?.forEach {
        $0.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: -15, right: 0)
        
        guard let view = $0.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView,
              let label = (view.subviews.compactMap{ $0 as? UILabel }).first,
              let imageView = (view.subviews.compactMap{ $0 as? UIImageView }).first else { return }
        
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        if CBServerManagerApi.sharedManager().currentUser.type == "Local" {
            label.text = titles[element]
        }
        label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false  
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
        ])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this with `UITabBarItem` because it doesn't have property `titleView` like `UINavigationItem`.

You can set only string as title and tab image. That's it.

If `UITabBarItem` had a `titleView` property then you would have the option to set a label as `titleView` with `numberOfLines` set to 0 but here you can only set the title as a string.