# How to make a UITabBar with multi-line itemTitle in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

currently I'm working in an iOS project in swift. In my project, I have UITabBarController, which contains five items. Now it is working fine no issue. But now I need to change the title to a bigger title. But after changing the title, the item title is not showing fully or in two lines. What I need is to list the title name in two lines. Is there any way to do that? I checked all the codes. Please help me.

Comment: You can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219860/multiple-lines-in-uitabbaritem-label

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple lines in UITabBarItem Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219860/multiple-lines-in-uitabbaritem-label)

Comment: I checked that solution.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge you can't achieve this with default tabor item. You must add custom view and design tabs by your own which explained below.

- Write a method like `addCustomTabbar()` in your `UITabBarController` subclassed class and call `addCustomTabbar()` method in `awakeFromNib()`.   - Hide default tab bar with `self.tabBar.isHidden = true`. This hides your default tab bar.
- Create your own `UIView` with frame is equal to tab bar frame like `let tabbarView = UIView(frame: tabBar.frame)`.
- From here onwards create a `UIButton` object with respective frame and add to your custom view i.e `tabbarView` like below.

  let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: individualWidth, height: Int(custom_tab_view.frame.height)))

As every `UIButton` had `titleLabel` , you can set number of lines property of the `titleLabel` is zero and text wrap is `wordWrap`. In this way, you can achieve title with multiple lines.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Let me try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    // access to list of tab bar items
    if let items = self.tabBar.items {
        for item in items {
            // here customise image insets top and bottom
            item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
            let viewTabBar = item.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
            if viewTabBar?.subviews.count == 2 {
            // here customise the label
                if let label = viewTabBar?.subviews[1] as? UILabel {
                    label.numberOfLines = 2
                    label.text = "Notification\rUpdates"
                    label.textAlignment = .center
                    label.frame = CGRect(x: label.frame.minX, y: label.frame.minY, width: 100, height: 25)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```