# How to add custom label on UITabbar first Item using Swift

Tags: swift

My scenario, I need to add one custom label on UITabbar first item center position, because based on label center position I am going to apply circle transition starting point on it.

My Code Below

```
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        transition.transitionMode = .present
        transition.startingPoint = customLabel.center // here I need to get custom label center position 
        return transition
    }

func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        transition.transitionMode = .dismiss
        transition.startingPoint =  customLabel.center
        return transition
    }
```

Comment: May be this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219860/multiple-lines-in-uitabbaritem-label) is useful for your query.